# Cant access instances from another instantiating the class

Tags: python, kivy

Using Kivy Factory I have instantiated my `MainWindow` class inside the `ApplyPage` class, Im trying to access the `self.placementtext` variable from my MainWindow class which is initialised as None, when I try to access it from the `ApplyPage` it returns as `None`. I know it returns as `None` because thats what I initialised it as but I would like to know any possible way to access the original value which it is assigned to in the `def printtext(self)` function. Any ideas on how to do this would be appreciate it here is my code.

```
class MainWindow(Screen):
    search_string1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    search_string2 = ObjectProperty(None)



    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.placementtext = None
        self.searchbutton = Button( pos_hint = {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}, size_hint= (0.2, 0.1), font_name = 'fonts/Qanelas-Heavy.otf', text= "Search", background_color = (0.082, 0.549, 0.984, 1.0),                            background_normal= '', font_size = 20)
        self.searchbutton.bind(on_release=self.searchpressed)
        self.add_widget(self.searchbutton)


    def searchpressed(self, instance):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        placements = database.child("placements").get()
        placementslist = placements.val()
        placementslist.items()
        for key, value in placementslist.items():
            self.key = key
            key_list = []
            key_list.append(key)
            for key in key_list:
                name = database.child("placements").child(str(key)).child("placement name").get()
                description = database.child("placements").child(str(key)).child("placement description").get()
                location = database.child("placements").child(str(key)).child("placement location").get()
                date = database.child("placements").child(str(key)).child("placement date").get()
                price = database.child("placements").child(str(key)).child("placement price").get()
                thelocalId = database.child("placements").child(str(key)).child("localId").get()
                self.thelocalId = thelocalId.val()
                data = "\n" + "\n" + str(name.val()) + '\n' + str(description.val()) + "\n" + str(
                    location.val()) + '\n' + str(date.val()) + '\n' + '\n' + str(price.val())
                project_list_screen = self.manager.get_screen('project_list_screen')
                project_list_screen.project_list.adapter.data.extend(["\n" + "\n" + str(name.val()) + '\n' + str(
                    description.val()) + "\n" + str(location.val()) + '\n' + str(date.val()) + '\n' + '\n' + str(
                    price.val())])
                project_list_screen.project_list._trigger_reset_populate()



                app.root.current = "project_list_screen"


    def printtext(self):
       self.placementtext = self.project_list_screen.project_list.adapter.selection[0]

Factory.register('MainWindow', cls=MainWindow)


class ApplyPage(Screen):
    mainwindow = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.mainwindow = kwargs.pop('mainwindow', None)
        super(ApplyPage, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.yes = Button(text="Yes", font_size = 20, font_name= "fonts/Qanelas-Heavy.otf", background_color = (0.082, 0.549, 0.984, 1.0), background_normal= '', pos_hint = {"x":0.1,"y":0.05}, size_hint= [0.2, 0.1])
        self.add_widget(self.yes)
        self.no = Button(text="No", font_size= 20, font_name= "fonts/Qanelas-Heavy.otf", background_color = (0.082, 0.549, 0.984, 1.0), background_normal= '', pos_hint = {"x":0.7, "y":0.05}, size_hint= [0.2, 0.1])
        self.add_widget(self.no)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        print(self.mainwindow.placementtext)
```

Here is how I instantiated the class in my kivy file

```
 ApplyPage:
        id: applyingpage
        name: "applyingpage"
        mainwindow: Factory.MainWindow()
```

Any help on how to access the `self.placementtext` original value would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lazy method is giving the app class a property which you feed the information into with your main screen and then read off with your second screen.

```
class MyApp(App):
    placementtext = None
```

so whenever you change your placement text (since its not a property cant use on_placementtext bind) simply add

```
app.placementtext = self.placementtext
```

and you can now access it from your second screen by calling on app.placementtext. eg:

```
def on_enter(self, *args):
    print(app.placementtext)
```

Another method is to use the Cache. First you register your Cache

```
Cache.register('windows')
```

then you add the mainwindow screen when you instantiate it

```
Cache.add('windows','mainwindow',#putyourmainwindowobjecthere)
```

now you can call on it from anywhere! eg:

```
def on_enter(self,*args):
    print(Cache.get('windows','mainwindow').placementtext)
```

Make sure you import the module from kivy first!

Hopefully that helps!